# Installing objdump on Ubuntu that recognizes mach-o binaries?

Tags: package-management, binutils, objdump

Anyone know how to install a version binutils on Ubuntu that has an objdump that can recognize a mach-o binary?

Currently when I run, `objdump -P load binary`, I get

> objdump: /path/to/binary: File format not recognized

I've tried installing the `binutils-multiarch` package, which gave me the same save error. I've also tried building from source using `./configure --enable-targets=all` (as recommend by https://stackoverflow.com/a/10186046/20774). But the resulting binary segfaults.

Any suggestions?